# React native for Android navigator geolocation not running

Tags: android, geolocation, react-native

On my iOS app the geolocation works fine and picks up my location on the watcher function.

However for Android, the code never seems to get executed on the success or fail callbacks when I put in alert's or console logs.

```
watchID: (null: ?number),

this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    (position) => {
        this.setState({ 
            userLocation: position,
            geo: true
        }, this.fetchBusinesses());
    },
    (error) => console.log(error.message),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 1000}
    );
```

Comment: As per here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html - do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in your manifest (on the JAVA side) ? Also, is there any info over in Android Studio as to any possible JAVA side errors in the process?

Comment: I do have that in my manifest XML file. When I removed it for testing it does alert me saying it's missing so it does acknowledge that it has been found. I'm not using Android Studio to compile `react-native run-android` on npm so I can't see any logs except for console.logs.

Comment: if you have a device attached to your machine you'll see lots of output from that in Android Studio even though you compile and run via terminal. It's helped me debug many-an-issue while coding in react. :) just worth checking out. Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: Are you testing in an emulator or on a device? If on an emulator which one?

Comment: It was because I was using an emulator. On a real device it works, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're using Genymotion, you need to explicitly enable GPS from right side menu before running the app in simulator.

Comment: I've got the same issue on a physical android device, my manifest has both android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION but still I can't get the location

Answer (score 3):

If you are running with newest Android, you manual set "Location" to on.
This switch is under Setting -> Apps -> {Your app} -> Permissions.[image]